# CLion Can't Find Visual Studio Compiler Even Though It's Installed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clion

I'm setting up my CLion compiler to use Visual Studio, but it says that the folder is not found.[image] But the folder does exist.[image] Even when I manually selected the Visual Studio folder, it says it doesn't exist. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Could you please add output from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat x86` to description? It could failed cause `ComSpec` is not found.

Answer (score 5):

[image]
Had same problem, in my case the C++/C build tools got uninstalled.

I resolved the issue by running **Visual Studio Installer**, In Workloads Tab tick "Desktop Development with C++", click install. After installation restart your computer.

Comment: I had same issue and just update MSVC - then restart and it works.